# Отключить клики айтемов RyclerView на 3 секунды

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, click, таймер

Есть 4 айтема `RecyclerView` клик реализовал по `LinerLayout`, если юзер нажмет на один из айтемов, нужно чтобы в течение 3 секунд клики у всех айтемов отключились, как быть?

**UPD**

Клик айтема из адаптера `RecyclerView`

```
holder.linearClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            // code
        }
    });
```

Мне именно в этот клик нужно установить отключение айтемов на 3 секунды. Я сделал простое `.setEnabled(false)` и кликнутый клик неактивен, но зато активны остальные 3. Мне нужно весь массив отключить в адаптере ресайкла

Comment: Вам нужно сделать их именно неактивными/некликабельными или просто что бы код в onClick'е не выполнялся?

Comment: У меня после клика задается цвет бэкграунда, 4 айтема, это варианты ответов, и соответственно после кликнутого ответа, мне нужно чтобы другие ответы были уже неактивны. И через 2 секунды вопрос меняется путем прокручивания `ViewPager` в котором все это находится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Завести поле для сохранения времени нажатия и при клике сравнивать с текущим временем:

```
private long mLastClickedTime;

-----------------------------

    public void onClick(View v) {
         long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
         if ((current - mLastClickedTime) < 3000L)
             return;
         mLastClickedTime = current;
         // some code
    }
```

Comment: Что то я ничего не понял, я извиняюсь. Сейчас обновлю вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Можно с CountDownTimer сделать

```
 ViewHolder.disableClick()
 new CountDownTimer(3000, 3000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {
     ViewHolder.enableClick()
 }
 }.start();
```

Comment: Логика в адаптере ресайкла у меня

Comment: Ну что можно сделать, после нажатия на item установить флаг блокировки и запросить обновление всего списка notifyDataSetChanged() и в onCreateViewHolder() выполнить блокировку клика у вьюх с таймером.